# What is the meaning of "I've got Australia"?

Tags: the-circle

In the science fiction movie, *The Circle (2017)*, Annie shows Mae a room where Bailey and Stenton make all of their plans. She is about to leave Mae:

> Mae: You're not coming back?
>
> Annie: I've got work.
>
> Mae: Annie, it's like, 11 o'clock.
>
> Annie: **I've got Australia** in a few minutes.

What is the meaning of "I've got Australia"?

Comment: You never get Australia. Australia gets YOU.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fairly typical American English office speak. Without having seen the film, I would assume it is a scheduled meeting or conference call with people in the Australia office.

Sydney is 16 hours ahead of New York, so a call at what I assume is 23:00 in America would put it during the afternoon of the next day in Aus.

Comment: Plausible explanation, but the folks in Australia must be real important if the Americans are staying up to 23 o'clock just to chat with them in the Australian afternoon.  At my place of work, we'd schedule it for late afternoon to early evening American time, early-to-mid morning Aussie time.  That way, disruption to everyone's schedule is minimized.

Comment: We stay up 'til 23:30 anyway, because of Colbert.

Comment: @Kevin I didn’t write the film.

Comment: My suggestion is that you ask this question on the “Movies and TV” site.  You’ll probably get more answers. (Not that I encourage double-posting).

Comment: @tale852150 actually, I’d said it’s really nothing to do with the film itself and ELL or English stack would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Darren - maybe so. Nonetheless, you might find that other people who have seen the movie might have asked the same question and got an answer on the “Movie & TV”.